# CNG Certificate Request, certificate needs to use CryptoAPI (legacy)

Tags: certificate, csr

We've created a CSR with Template "(No template) CNG key" and received our certificate from a valid CA.

However, it seems our product (VMWare Horizon) doesn't like CNG and we are trying to figure if we can convert the CSR and/or certificate to the legacy CryptoAPI.

I've found command such as:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in cert.crt -out cert.pem
```

But which result in this error:

```
140403888732064:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag:tasn_dec.c:1343:
140403888732064:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error:tasn_dec.c:393:Type=PKCS12
```

So I guess the certificate I've received is already x509 and not pkcs12.

Is there a way to achieve what I'm trying to achieve without create a new CSR and requesting a new certificate to my CA?

Comment: You must create new CSR using legacy CSP. There is no way to reuse old CSR.